# Transform C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, transform

I have a code that calculate the sum of a certain number of points, multiplied by the total of the questions asked, divided per 20. 
The thing is that the sum of a certain number of points is in vector type, and the number of the questions total is a double. So I need to convert vector in double. 
I got this code

```
return std::accumulate(begin(chiffre), end(chiffre), 0.0, [](double a, double b)->double { return a + b * 20;}) / nbtotal;
```

But this is C++11 and I program not using C++11, so I need to convert this code into C++98. And I really don't know how to proceed.
If someone can help, don't hesitate ! And sorry for my english !! :)

Comment: What is chiffre? Btw., C++11 *is* C++. If there is no reason speaking against it, maybe update your compiler.

Comment: You should create named function object, construct it and pass it in the same way as lambda. Also if `chiffre` is a normal container you should replace external `begin`, `end` with `chiffre.begin()`, `chiffre.end()` respectively.

Comment: And the `*20` and `/nbtotal` part in your code and in your description are exact opposites

Comment: Your code does the opposite of what you say. Multiplies by 20 and divides by `nbtotal`. Also, I don't understand your problem. You don't know how to convert `accumulate` into a normal `for` loop? Btw multiplication distributes over addition - `ac + bc = (a+b)*c`.

Comment: @luk32 std::accumulate is valid pre-c++11 too, just the lambda expression not

Comment: @deviantfan Oh, then the effort put into question is even more baffling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just create a normal function:

```
static double myAdd(double a, double b) {
    return a + b * 20;
} 

//...
return std::accumulate(chiffre.begin(), chiffre.end(), 0.0, myAdd) / nbtotal;
```

You also have to change `begin(chiffre)` to `chiffre.begin()` and the same for `end`, because these global functions appeared only in C++11 (given that you didn't write them yourself).